# How StandardPBEStringEncryptor works?

Tags: encryption, java

I have to encrypt some String data and be able to decrypt them.
So i tried Java simplified encryption (Jasypt), i used StandardPBEStringEncryptor.
It works i can encrypt and decrypt, but i don't understand **how this algorithm can decrypt the crypted string** from the password i have set, while the salt seems to be random ? 
When i encrypt a same string, the crypted result is always different.
http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guesses are correct:

- it uses a random salt.
- it needs that salt to perform the decryption is correct.

From the [documentation](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html#encrypt(java.lang.String)):

> This encryptor uses a salt for each encryption operation. The size of the salt depends on the algorithm being used. This salt is used for creating the encryption key and, if generated by a random generator, it is also appended unencrypted at the beginning of the results so that a decryption operation can be performed.

The salt is appended in the encryption result, so it will be available during the decryption process.

Comment: So is the salt usefull while he isn't encrypted ?

Comment: @AlexMel: The salt is useful to make brute-force attacks more difficult, according to the documentation. A salt isn't a secret, so it doesn't need to be encrypted.